# Prob. In Downloading VLC

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to download VLC, when the download process complete, this pops out:

> **NSIS  Error**
>
> Installer integrity check has failed. Common causes include incomplete download and damaged media. Contact the installer's author to obtain a new copy.
>
> More information at:
>   http://nsis.sf.net/NSIS_Error

Answer (score 2):

The VLC download website selects the nearest mirror from the list of available mirrors. Your problem downloading VLC may be solved by selecting a different mirror. The official [VideoLAN website](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/2.2.1/win32/vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe) has four alternate mirrors. To show the alternate mirrors, click on where it says: *If you have a problem, click here*.

Comment: http://mirror.vodien.com/videolan/vlc/2.2.1/win32/vlc-2.2.1-win32.exe seems to work for me. Of course, this link would only be valid for the current version

Comment: Why would selecting a different mirror help?

Comment: I've had the problem before when selecting mirrors after selecting the nearest mirror that the download was interrupted partway through, so that the file was not completely downloaded, but after selecting what looked like a more frequently used mirror the download was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the downloaded installer is faulty.

I'm assuming you downloaded it from http://www.videolan.org/, and they have a checksum listed for the current download - check it with [FCIV](http://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/confirmation.aspx?id=11533) or some other sha1 hashing tool to make sure its valid.

I typically do my installs off [ninite](https://ninite.com/) (though I may want to move to [chocolaty](https://chocolatey.org/)), which might be an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You want to likely install a reputable download manager such as [DownThemAll!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for Firefox or [Chrono Download Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrono-download-manager/mciiogijehkdemklbdcbfkefimifhecn?hl=en) for Chrome.

"Browser-only" downloads are prone to corruption in my experience (Firefox seems especially eager to terminate downloads before the last few bits are actually processed). A quality third-party download manager will generally solve many of these problems or otherwise clearly indicate the failure of the download.